# Shorthand way of writing "if value is equal to this or this"

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I searched but couldn't find what I was looking for. I have the below piece of code:

```php
if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ] === "/post" || $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ] === "/post/" ) {

    // redirect to "/"

} else {

    // logic to display the post (uri to db query)

}
```

Works fine, as expected. I tried to shorten the comparison to (truncated):

```php
...... $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ] === "/post" || "/post/" .......
```

I didn't expect it to work, actually expected it to throw an error to be honest. No errors, but now any URI for this page; `/post`, `/post/`, `/post/my-first-post` all execute the if part of the if/else statement.

The second part will never be executed. Why is this and what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: There is no shortcut for this.

Comment: You can change it on `in_array($_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ],["/post","/post/"])`

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks, I meant to add (if there is a way) to the end of the question. Thanks for clearing that up, it feels like there should be a shorter way to write this!

Comment: `'foo'==='bar' || 'baz'`evaluates to true, the LHS evaluates to false, and here the string `'baz'` evaluates to true.  `false || true` is `true`, hence your condition is always satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative using a simple regex:

```
if (preg_match('~^/post/?$~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  // ...
}
```

This matches `/post` and an optional trailing slash with `/?`.

Answer (score 2):

Using **in_array()** u can shorten your code.

```
$rurl_route_list=['/post', '/post/']

if ( in_array($_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ], $url_route_list)) {

    // redirect to "/"

} else {

    // logic to display the post (uri to db query)

}
```

Comment: It was a comment

Comment: while opening the question i saw only one comments.After post my answer i saw ur comments.your answer is right.

Comment: @AksenP, why comment when you could have answered?

Comment: @Progrock, using of function is not the same as shorthand, I thought so)

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I accepted the other answer because in this scenario it has shortened the code considerably, but this answer also has lots of valid uses, thank you.